# two mysql inserts both or nothing

Tags: mysql, forms

I have a form that posts to php.  As part of the post, I need to insert data into 2 different tables.  Right now I am just doing one insert followed by the second insert.

You can probably already tell what I'm going to ask next :)

I need to be able to ensure both inserts happen.  If the second one doesn't happen, I need the first one not to happen or be rolled back.

My understanding is this is possible in mysql if it is using innodb, which is the default for mysql 5.5 and above however I'm on mysql 5.3 which is the latest release for centos.  Not sure how I can tell, and if innodb is turned on, how do I write my query?  And then of course I might have to assume that anyone else who might use my program might not have the right version of mysql with innodb.

Thanks

Comment: See MySQL Docs on [TRANSACTION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your table you can specify wich engine it should run. To be able to use transactions it need to in InnoDB. That part of [`CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) is at the end in *table options*. If your table isn't already InnoDB you can change it with `ALTER TABLE`.

It's possible to set auto_commit to false from php and that is what you want to do. Then everything you do will be inside one transaction until you do a commit or rollback.

The other alternativ is to manually send `START TRANSACTION`, `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`. There is an example in the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-ms.quickstart.transactions.php).

Comment: You should be using InnoDB regardless, as MyISAM is not journaled and might crumple and lose all your data if it gets corrupted.

Comment: I agree completely and I didn't say anything else. It's just that in the scope of this question I mention that OP needs to use InnoDB for the transaction support.

Comment: Just adding my two cents. Maybe should've prefixed that with "+1".

Answer (score 0):

```
START TRANSACTION

if(first insert failed)
{
    ROLLBACK
}
else if(second insert failed)
{
    ROLLBACK
}
else
{
    COMMIT
}
```